# ngrx: Adjusting the properties of a child state to support reusability

Tags: angular, ngrx

**Problem Description:**

I often re-use common UI elements, for example this “Datatable”:

[image]

Whenever adding a feature to this table, we have to add the feature individually in every module, resulting in lots of wasted work and code repetition.

**Solution Proposal:**

I’d like to create a single stateful implementation of this table as an ngModule, so that when we make an adjustment to the core behavior of the table (adding a feature for example), that we only have to make the change in one place.

It has proven difficult to implement this. The main issue I can’t seem to get around is that multiple instances of the dataTable means that when one instance dispatches a new action, every instance processes it in its respective reducer.

In an attempt to solve this, I’ve implemented the following scaffolding:

```
Store
→ featureA
    → dataTable
→ featureB
    → dataTable
```

Then on the dataTable component’s ngOnInit() function, I dispatch an “InitTable” action with a “forFeature” payload with an identifier to specify which feature the action is for.

Then in both featureA & B, I have an effect that listens for an InitTable Action with the forFeature property that matches their identifier, and then dispatches a ‘feature-specific’ action. This seems to work appropriately

```
@Effect()
  tableInit$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    filter((x: Action) => x['forFeature'] && x['forFeature'] === 'A'), // ‘A’ as id
    ofType(<string>DataTableActionTypes.InitTable),
    map((action: Action) => {
      return new InitATable(); // Action specified at the ‘feature’ level
    })
  );
```

This action should then be caught by a reducer at the feature level, and adjust a field on its child dataTable state. I can’t seem to get this part to work, and I wonder if it violates the pattern to attempt to adjust a child’s state at a parent level? Below is a rough estimate of how I imagine the code to look:

```
export function aReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case AActionTypes.InitATable: {
      return { ...state, dataTable: { ...state.dataTable, feature: ‘A’ } }
    }

    ....
```

}
}

Following this, inside of the dataTable’s reducer, before entering the typical switch statement, I return the original state if the dataTable if the identifier in the action’s forFeature property is not equal to the identifier contained by the dataTable state’s ‘feature’ field.

```
export function dataTableReducer(state, action) {
  if(action.forFeature !== state.feature){
    return state;
  }
  switch(action.type){
    case AActionTypes.InitATable: {
      return { ...state, dataTable: { ...state.dataTable, feature: ‘A’ } }
    }

    ....
```

}
}

I believe that should work, provided I figure out a way to individually set the ‘feature’ value of the different dataTables.

UPDATE: Contrary to what I initially thought, Hacking around and debugging has shown that the issue is not that there are different instances of dataTable, each hearing the actions intended for other datraTables, but that each different reference to a child dataTable in fact points to the same instance.

Comment: I would do in another way: just created reducers with actionName param and make actionName also as input param in component. And put them on different state properties as you actually did